# Why var and *var returns the same?

Tags: reference, rust

I am learning Rust and I am having a little difficulty with references and related, and I didn't got one thing:

```
fn main() {
    let number = &mut 0;

    println!("Ref: {}, Value: {}", number, *number);

    *number += 1;

    println!("Ref: {}, Value: {}", number, *number);
}
```

The output is 0 for both ref and value in the first *println!* and 1 for both ref and value in the second *println!*, wich doesn't make sense, as I added one to the referenced value, not the reference itself. Indeed, trying to add any value to the reference itself yields an error. Why *number* and **number* are returning the same value?

Comment: Related: [What are Rust's exact auto-dereferencing rules?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28519997/3425536)

Comment: println is dereferencing the pointer automatically, so they print the same thing.